# Drawing a circle with JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I want to draw this drawing

[image]

I could have made a similar shape but I could not color the dots.
That's my code. Can you help me to get the visual product

```java
public class ProjeGorsel extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Circle circle1 = new Circle();
        Circle circle2 = new Circle();
        circle1.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle1.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));
        circle1.setRadius(100);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.RED);
        circle1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle1.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(2d, 21d);
        circle1.setStrokeWidth(3);

        circle2.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle2.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));
        circle2.setRadius(50);
        circle2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        circle2.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle2.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(2d, 21d);
        circle2.setStrokeWidth(3);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ShowCircle");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice, don't try to do this with a stroke dash array.  Instead of plotting two circles, plot hundreds.  Just adapt this [createTicks function](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3388637#file-analogueclock-java-L70) to plot circles rather than lines.